# Has someone tried SoftiWARP?

Tags: infiniband, rdma

I'm trying to use SoftiWARP for a project. I installed it using instructions from [here](http://0x8086.blogspot.com/2011/12/setting-up-softiwarp-in-debian-60-from.html), which I followed to the word, except I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 server.

To test it out, I used the client-server programs from the-geek-in-the-corner (https://github.com/tarickb/the-geek-in-the-corner). I'm getting errors and segmentation faults while using it. For example, here is an error sequence for the first program:

1. Start the server: ./server
2. Run the client: ./client
3. I can run the client successfully a few (>=0) number of times, but I eventually get the following error at the client:

address resolved.
route resolved.
on_event: unknown event.
on_completion: status is not IBV_WC_SUCCESS

So, my question is if anyone has code that has been tested with SoftiWARP? I'd also appreciate any comments on SoftiWARP's stability (i.e. does it work with unmodified ibverbs code?).

Answer (score 1):

iWARP requires the IBV_ACCESS_REMOTE_WRITE to be set for both read and write MRs contrary to InfiniBand where you only use IBV_ACCESS_REMOTE_READ for reads and IBV_ACCESS_REMOTE_WRITE for writes. See in the perftest code [here](http://git.openfabrics.org/git?p=~grockah/perftest.git;a=blob;f=src/perftest_resources.c;hb=HEAD#l459) for an example of how to support both iWARP and InfiniBand when register MRs.

If the code you're testing is not working correctly on iWARP but works properly under regular InfiniBand then it might not be setting the correct flags when registering memory and thus might be crashing because of that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what caused the original issue, but after working with SoftiWARP for a month, I will vouch for it.

It seems pretty stable and all my IB code works on it. It is good for someone who wants to learn verbs programming but does not have access to IB hardware.